# Highlight new entries on inbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox

I think it would help to see what's new. I don't have much to add, it's a simple feature that IMO would make things look a little better. The image explains the feature request.

[image: Highlight]

Comment: There's a hellofalot that could be optimized in that dialog.  I'm sitting back and watch it grow.  Give them a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been deployed now.

Note that if an item has been "collapsed" (like comments are) then if even 1 item in the collapsed set is new it will be highlighted.

Basically, the # of new messages is not necessarily equal to the # of highlighted blocks.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's looking cuter (more than it already is) :)